# Facebook FriendPickerSample android project not showing friend list

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I downloaded Android Facebook SDK from [this](http://www.4shared.com/zip/sE-zpFs6/facebook-android-sdk-35.htm?locale=en) link.And tried to execute the FriendPicker sample project.But it shows response of `No friends selected` as per the given image. When I click the `Pick Friends` Button on this project it will show the popup window.While click the ok from shown window the response will be `connection lost`.So anyone please help me how to run this App successfully.

[image].
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of may be your key hash has not been matched.so try to replace some character in your key hash as per mentioned below.

Facebook some how replaces +,- and / with _

So just try replacing _ with +, - with / and add that hash-key.